# I was trying to experiment on call by pointers.But i encountered segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to dereference pointer variable `x` with pointer variable `t` declared in the function `s(int *x,int *y)`? 
If i use the datatype of t to be integer rather than pointer to integer,it works fine.I am unable to find the logic why it gives segmentation fault on changing to pointer variable.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void s(int *x,int *y)
{
    int *t;
    *t=*x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=*t;
}
int main()
{
    int a=3,b=5;
    s(&a,&b);
    cout<<" a:"<<a<<" b:"<<b<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Segmentation fault                                                                                                            


...Program finished with exit code 139                                                                                        
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

Comment: `t` isn't allocated. Do `int t = *x; *x = *y; *y = t;`

Comment: Use references instead of pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you are trying use a swap function, to swap values of two variables and "s" is your swap function. In that case you should code like this..

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void s(int *x,int *y)
{
    int t;
    t=*x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=t;
}
int main()
{
    int a=3,b=5;
    s(&a,&b);
    cout<<" a:"<<a<<" b:"<<b<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In your original code you are referencing t without initializing it. Hence the segmentation fault.However, for swap you don't need t as a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
    int *t;
    *t=*x;
```

Says:

1. Give me enough memory to hold a pointer to an `int` and call that pointer `t`
2. Copy the value stored at the memory pointed to by `x` into the memory pointed to by `t`.

The question is: where is `t` pointing? We don't know. It's uninitialized. Using uninitialized values is bad and the behavior is undefined. If you're lucky you get a segfault. If you're unlucky, the program keeps operating as if nothing happened until 2 weeks later when your 1,000,000 line of code enterprise application crashes.

See: https://en.cppreference.com/book/uninitialized

Answer (score 0):

You never allocate memory for your `int` pointer

In C++ pointers have to have their memory allocated from the free store manually, otherwise they point to a non-existent - zero size (well really pointer size) - memory location. Since you have not allocated any space for your int pointer to point too you get a segfault when trying to access that location.

You need to allocate memory for it with `new`. Example:

```cpp
int* t = new int(1);
```

You then need to delete with it delete

```cpp
delete t
```

I would pick up a book on C++ and pointers before going any further

Comment: "In C++ pointers have to have their memory allocated from the free store manually" this is not true, you can easily do `int tmp; int *t = &tmp;` though it does not make much sense in this case, `int tmp` should be used directly then.

Comment: Ok more accurately then points *should* have the memory location they point to allocated manually. I sincerely hope you are not suggesting making a pointer to a stack object is a good idea

Comment: Pointer to automatic variable is perfectly fine and in this case it is much better than your suggested manual call to `new` and `delete` as memory will be deallocated automatically.

Comment: ? Not if the pointer exists in a different scope. Not quite sure what you mean

Comment: I don't like naked pointers actually and much prefer smart pointers but in terms of the basic free store references pointing to stack references it sounds like a segfault waiting to happen

Comment: I mean in this exact function you can create `int` variable right before pointer `t` and make `t` point to it. Then at the end of function this memory will be automatically deallocated so you do not need to use `delete`. It does not make much sense as `int` varaible can be used directly without any pointer but your manual `new` and `delete` has even less sense in this particular case.

Comment: My manual new and delete is correct for what I described above, free store allocation of a naked integer. I agree it is a terrible way of doing things in real code but as a demonstration of what was wrong with the OPs code I think it is good. As I understand it the OP is testing something here and not actually thinking of doing the above in real code

Answer (score 0):

`t` isn't allocated, therefore when you do `*t = *x`, it is "undefined behaviour". It's good that your code fails, because, it can actually work sometimes (with UB, anything can happen). Do the following instead to avoid useless dynamic memory allocation.

```
int t = *x;
*x = *y;
*y = t;
```